# How can I move a tkinter canvas-window by the mouse-pointer?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a tkinter Canvas where some objects are placed and can be moved by the mouse pointer. One of these objects is a text, which is not implemented as canvas-text-item but as a text-widget in a canvas-window-item, as I want to implement syntax highlighting for the text. I know how to implement the move-feature for a canvas-text-item but I am not able to implement the same feature for a canvas-window-item. I believe the reason is that when the mouse pointer is inside the canvas-window-item, it not inside the canvas anymore. This is my example code, where moving text1 works, but moving text2 fails:

```
    import tkinter as tk
    event_x = None
    event_y = None
    
    def end_move_text(event, item_id):
        canvas_id.tag_unbind(item_id, "<Motion>"         )
        canvas_id.tag_unbind(item_id, "<ButtonRelease-1>")
    
    def move_text(event, item_id):
        global event_x, event_y
        canvas_id.move(item_id, event.x-event_x, event.y-event_y)
        event_x, event_y = event.x, event.y
    
    def move_start_text(event, item_id):
        global event_x, event_y
        event_x, event_y = event.x, event.y
        canvas_id.tag_bind(item_id, "<Motion>"         , lambda event : move_text    (event, item_id))
        canvas_id.tag_bind(item_id, "<ButtonRelease-1>", lambda event : end_move_text(event, item_id))
    
    root = tk.Tk()
    canvas_id = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=200)
    
    canvas_text = canvas_id.create_text(50,50, text="text1", tag="text1", font=("Courier", 10))
    canvas_rect = canvas_id.create_rectangle(canvas_id.bbox(canvas_text), outline="black", tag="text1")
    canvas_id.tag_bind(canvas_text, "<Button-1>", lambda event: move_start_text(event, "text1"))
    
    text_widget = tk.Text(canvas_id, height=1, width=5, relief="flat", font=("Courier", 10))
    text_widget.insert("1.0", "text2")
    canvas_wind = canvas_id.create_window(150, 50)
    canvas_id.itemconfig(canvas_wind, window=text_widget)
    canvas_id.tag_bind(canvas_wind, "<Button-1>", lambda event: move_start_text(event, canvas_wind)) # does not work
    
    canvas_id.grid()
    root.mainloop()
```

As a workaround I implemented a binding of Button-1 directly to the canvas, where I check if there is any canvas-item near the mouse-pointer and if yes this canvas item is moved. But then the user has to click "near" the object to move and not "at" the object to move, which is bad user experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply bind `<B1-Motion>` on the text widget instead:

```py
def move_item_window(event, item_id):
    # get the bounding box of the widget
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas_id.bbox(item_id)
    # calculate the center point inside the bounding box
    cx, cy = (x2-x1)/2, (y2-y1)/2
    # move the widget by the distance between the mouse position and the center point
    canvas_id.move(item_id, event.x-cx, event.y-cy)

text_widget.bind("<B1-Motion>", lambda e: move_item_window(e, canvas_wind))
```

Comment: The answer works as expected. But cx, cy are not the canvas coordinates of the center point of the widget. cx is half the width and cy is half the height of the widget. But because the widget is located inside a canvas_window which has its own coordinate-system (starting with 0,0 at the left upper corner), cx and cy can be used as coordinates  into this canvas_window coordinates system. The event coodinates are also based on the canvas_window coordinate system, so they can be used to determine the delta for a move.

Answer (score 1):

I have added an answer to my own question after reading the answer from @acw1668 as it included some valuable ideas which enabled me to simplify my example a lot. By taking the center of the widget as a reference point it is not necessary anymore to track the dedicated reference point event_x, event_y. By using "B1-Motion" instead of "Motion" the dynamical binding actions are not necessary anymore.

```
import tkinter as tk

def move_item(event, item_id):
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas_id.bbox(item_id)
    if canvas_id.type(item_id)=="window":
        cx, cy = (x2-x1)/2, (y2-y1)/2 # Width and height of item_id calculated from canvas-coordinates
    else:
        cx, cy = (x2+x1)/2, (y2+y1)/2 # Center of item_id in canvas-coordinates
    canvas_id.move(item_id, event.x-cx, event.y-cy)

root = tk.Tk()
canvas_id = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=200)

canvas_text = canvas_id.create_text(50,50, text="text1", tag="text1", font=("Courier", 10))
canvas_rect = canvas_id.create_rectangle(canvas_id.bbox(canvas_text), outline="black", tag="text1")
canvas_id.tag_bind(canvas_text, "<B1-Motion>", lambda event: move_item(event, "text1"))

text_widget = tk.Text(canvas_id, height=1, width=5, relief="flat", font=("Courier", 10))
text_widget.insert("1.0", "text2")
canvas_wind = canvas_id.create_window(150, 50)
canvas_id.itemconfig(canvas_wind, window=text_widget)
text_widget.bind("<B1-Motion>", lambda e: move_item(e, canvas_wind))

canvas_id.grid()
root.mainloop()
```